# How to Turn a Raspberry Pi 3 into Wi-Fi hotspot with USB data modem

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hotspot

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and USB data modem that connects to the internet. I want to connect the USB data modem to Raspberry Pi 3 and I would like to create a Wi-Fi hotspot (Access Point) from Raspberry Pi 3. So that mobile devices can connect to Raspberry Pi's hotspot and get onto the internet.

I don't want to use Ethernet cable for this, only USB data modem.

Comment: The USB data modem connects to the internet and you want that your mobile devices connect to the hotspot from the RasPi and can go into the internet, is it that what you mean?

Comment: yes. I will plug in the usb data modem to raspberry pi 3, and  want to create a hotspot in RasPi, so that other mobile device can connect to hotspot and get internet connection.

Comment: I don't know your USB modem. So please connect it to the raspi and establish an internet connection so you can `ping google.com` from the raspi. Then edit your question and insert the output from this command: `ip addr`. I need that to make routing/bridging to the access point.